Дискорд бот не может сразу и использовать команды и присылать сообщения
Вот код:
import discord,asyncio
from discord.ext import commands


client = discord.Client(intents=(discord.Intents.all()))
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix,intents=(discord.Intents.all()))


@bot.command()
async def buy(ctx):
    await ctx.reply(f"{buyMessage}")

@bot.command()
async def покупка(ctx):
    await ctx.reply(f"{buyMessage}")


async def sendMassage(channel_id: int, msg):
    
    print(f"Massage Sended With Text ({msg})")

    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(msg)




@client.event
async def on_ready():
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(sendMessage(chat_id,"Hello"), client.loop)


bot.run('TOKEN')
client.run('TOKEN')

Однако если я добавляю эту строку - bot.run('TOKEN'), то программа такое ощущение игнорирует client.run('TOKEN'). Как можно запустить и то, и то?

зачем и то и то? замените @client.event на @bot.event и запускайте только bot.run(), а client вообще удалите из кода везде

Почитайте в чем разница между discord.Client и commands.Bot. Это не работает так, что client — только для событий, а bot — только для команд.

.run блокируют друг друга, что приводит к тому, что двух ботов таким способом запустить невозможно.
